# I am very confused. Please help me to resolve this

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class TreeNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
         self.val = val
         self.left = left
         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def isSubtree(self, s: TreeNode, t: TreeNode) 
       if TreeNode(0) == TreeNode(0):
           print("yes")
```

Why are these two nodes not equal?

Comment: You have not defined what it means for two ``TreeNode``s to be equal. Does the value have to match? Are left and right important? You must explicitly tell Python by defining an ``__eq__`` method.

Comment: i just want to know why i got false when i have same val for two tree with same left and right ....

Comment: Because you did not define that "same val for two tree with same left and right" means the two nodes are equal.

Comment: just forget all the line instead of if statement,when i have a function for making  tree,and i have two trees,p = treenode(val=0,left=None,right=None),and q=treenode(val=0,left=None,right=None),then is p==q or not,if not then why?????

Answer (score 2):

Because the two objects are distinct instances. By default, python compare the memory adresses of objects.

To make it work, you need to implement a `__eq__()` methods in TreeNode to redefine how to compare this objects.